# My post repeats itself on the second page

Tags: query-posts, navigation, get-posts

Hey the way i have my index coded is that it shows one full post and the rest of the post are excerpts, but when i click previous the 2nd page shows the same post from the first page, what can i do to change this.

Here is my index.php file

```
                                                    <?php get_header() ?>

    <div id="content">          
 <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
 <?php $count = 0; ?>

 <?php 
 query_posts('cat=0'); while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
 ?>
 <?php $count++; ?>

 <?php if ($count <= 1) : ?>


    <div class="entry-single">
            <div class="entry-top">

                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php printf( __('Permalink to %s', 'wpbx'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ) ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>

                <div class="entry-meta-top">
                    <span class="entry-date"><font color="#e60288"><b><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></b></font></span>
                    <span class="entry-meta-sep">|</span>
                    <span class="entry-cat">Published in <?php the_category(','); ?> </span>

            </div>
 <div id="sharing">
 <span class='st_facebook_hcount' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php          the_permalink(); ?>' displayText='share'></span><span class='st_twitter_hcount'     st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' displayText='share'></span><span class='st_plusone_hcount' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' displayText='share'></span></div>
                </div>

            <div class="entry-content clearfix">
                <?php the_content('<p align="right"><b>Read More     »</b></p>') ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="page-  link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'wpbx' ) . '&after=</div>') ?>
            </div>

               <div class="entry-meta entry-bottom">
  <?php the_tags( __( '<span class="tag-links">More On: ', 'wpbx' ), ", ", "</span>\n" ) ?>

        <div id="footshare"><span class='st_facebook_hcount' st_title='<?php      the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' displayText='share'></span><span class='st_twitter_hcount' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' displayText='share'></span><span class='st_plusone_hcount' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' displayText='share'></span></div>

 <div id="footcomm"><span class="entry-comm"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave A Comment', 'wpbx' ), __( '1 Reaction', 'wpbx' ), __( '% Reactions', 'wpbx' ) ) ?></span></div>

            </div>

 <?php else : ?>


 <div class="entry">
        <div class="entry-top">



        </div>

            <div class="entry-content clearfix">

                <div class= "entry-list-thumb">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="    <?php printf(__( 'Read %s', 'wpbx' ), wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="entry-content">

 <h2 class="entry-title2"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php printf( __('Permalink to %s', 'wpbx'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ) ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>

 <div class="entry-meta-top">
                <span class="entry-date"><font color="#89f800"><b>     <?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></b></font></span>
                <span class="entry-meta-sep">|</span>
                <span class="entry-comm">Published in <?php the_category(', '); ?></span>
            </div>

        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>



                </div>

            </div>



 <div class="entry-meta entry-bottom2">

<div id="footshare2"><a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php the_title(); ?> http://celebloid.com/?p=<?php the_ID(); ?>" title="Share This Article On Twitter!" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.celebloid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/twittershare.png"></a> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Share this on Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.celebloid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/facebookshare.png"></a> <a class="addthis_button_email"><img src="http://www.celebloid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/emailshare.png"></a> <a href="http://addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250&amp;username=ra-4f481f3e69cf1512" class="addthis_button_compact"><img src="http://www.celebloid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/moreshare.png"></a></div>

 <div id="footshare4"><?php the_tags( __( '<span class="tag-links">More On: ', 'wpbx' ), ", ", "</span>\n" ) ?></div>

 <div id="footcommm"><span class="entry-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php printf(__('Continue reading %s'), wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>"><?php _e( '<img src="http://www.celebloid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/readmore.jpg">', 'wpbx' ) ?></a></span></div>

            </div>


 <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- .post -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php else : ?>
 <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="navigation clearfix">
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link(__( 'Previous <span class="meta-nav">Articles</span>', 'wpbx' )) ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link(__( 'Next <span class="meta-nav">Articles</span>', 'wpbx' )) ?></div>

        </div>

    </div><!-- #content -->

 <?php get_sidebar() ?>
 </div>
 <?php get_footer() ?>
```

The reason i query my post is because i made a custom featured content slide that only gets post from a certain category.

Without the post being query it only pulls post from the category on the content slide.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead for query post. Parameter 'paged' is which that keep track of the pagination so you have to pass it on query posts.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
                'cat' => 0,
                'paged' => $paged
                );
query_posts($args);
```

Also try to avoid `query_posts()` unless its absolutely necessary. Use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts).

Comment: That isn't working for me, it gives me an error saying  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in /hermes/bosweb/web188/b1885/ipg.celebloidcom1/wp-content/themes/celebloid/index.php on line 139` and on that line is `<?php endwhile; ?>` and when i took that off it only showed the post from the 2nd page on the first page

Comment: the code suggested by @prionkor has to replace exactly this section `query_posts('cat=0');`

Comment: I found a solution, after looking for codes and implementing a lot of them, i just added a line to the origial get_post. Here is what i added and now the pages work perfectly :) I'm happy.

     `<?php  query_posts( array( 'cat' => -0, 'paged'=> $paged ) ); while(have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>`               i don't have a higher enough reputation to answer :(